# How to use httpurlconnection.openconnection without any proxy if the proxy is set at Global level?

Tags: java, proxy, httpurlconnection

My application uses some proxy which is set at global level.So,even after doing httpurlconnection.openconnection (not httpurlconnection.openconnection (proxy) which takes proxy as parameter) ,the connection is made through the proxy. I would like to know if I can not use the default proxy in cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies if the question was not clear.I finally figured it out myself.If proxy is set at system level,httpurlconnection.openconnection() will use the proxy even if we do not pass a proxy object.However to override it we can use  -

```
httpurlconnection.openconnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY)
```

By passing NO_PROXY the connection will not use proxy for the connection even if it is set as global level.